# get customer info based on email address using rest API in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have a requirement that I need to migrate users from a remote RMS to existing magento 2 website using Rest API. Migration will either create new user if it doesn't exists or will update the existing user. For both cases I need to find if a particular user having an email address already exists in the magento system or not. If the user exists then I need th customerId (PK) so that I can send the customerID with updated customer details in the api.

So is there any way to find user details using customer email address in magento 2 using REST API? Please let me know.

Thanks
Jawed

Comment: you can use `/V1/customers/:email/activate` rest api list of api http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html and for examples http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-api/

Comment: Thanks for the response : I am using this url  and it's giving me error : http://localhost/rest/V1/customers/jawed@abc.in/activate       Error =>   {
  "message": "Request does not match any route.",
  "trace": null
}

Answer (score 1):

By now, I'm sure you've moved on. But, to anyone else that might get here wondering the same thing.

There's two ways to solve this:

Method 1: use `GET /V1/customers/isEmailAvailable`

This method is nice since it just returns a simple `true`|`false` on whether the email is inuse/available for that particular website ID.

Method 2 (my preference): you merely need to "search" for the customer based on their email.

The following REST call will return you the customer record based on their email or an empty set (as of v2.3):

`GET /V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=email&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=<email_address>&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq`

replace `<email_address>` with the URL encoded email you are checking.